# jQuery Isotope `arrangeComplete` listener does not fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I have the following jQuery code using Isotope plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /**
     * Initialise Isotope
     */
    var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
        "itemSelector": ".grid-item",
        layoutMode: 'masonry',
        "masonry": {
            "columnWidth": 0
        }
    });

    /**
     * Trigger when arrangement completes
     */
    $grid.on( 'arrangeComplete', function( event, filteredItems ) {
        alert("HERE!");
    });

});
```

The alert does not trigger at all although the Isotope grid works. What have I missed? Thanks!

Comment: Need a link or a jsfiddle. Also, if you are not using isotope v2.2.0 or later, arrangeComplete was not added until this version

Answer (score 1):

I got my code working with the following change:

```
$('.grid').isotope().on( 'layoutComplete', function( event, filteredItems ) {
    alert("HERE!");
});
```

I got the `arrangeComplete` [from here](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/events.html) so I do not understand why it does not work, as I have Isotope 2.2.2 which is the latest version. `layoutComplete` did the trick, which I found with some research.

Answer (score 1):

```js
 $grid.on('arrangeComplete', function() {
  console.log('arrangeComplete')
 }).isotope();
```